# Cannot make a deep link into a standalone app with no custom scheme defined, stack:

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

Getting this error after deploying my app to Alpha but Prod version works great on all the devices and platforms. found this from google play console crash report but couldn't find any possible reason and solution for this.

```
Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Cannot make a deep link into a standalone app with no custom scheme defined, stack:
<unknown>@854:963
E@836:3496
<unknown>@836:567
<unknown>@460:2224
h@2:1585
<unknown>@6:57
h@2:1585
d@2:958
global code@1241:3
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)
```